# How to get the size of the text in a button

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I get the width and height of the text in a button?

I can't think of anything to use to compute for it.

Comment: `Graphics.MeasureString` maybe?

Comment: That depends on what's the measure for. Just for drawing the text of a custom Button? If you draw the text using `Graphics.DrawString()`, then use `Graphics.MeasureString()`, if you use `TextRenderer.DrawText()`, then `TextRenderer.MeasureText()`. For other uses, there's [MeasureCharacterRanges()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.measurecharacterranges)

Comment: @Jimi thank you!, Could you post your comment as an answer so I could mark it as the right one.